# Discord.js Errors in pay command

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm facing a problem for a few days in the "pay" command in my little economy system, what I'm trying to do is, when executing the command for example "pay @user 2k" it recognizes as just "2 coins ", how can I make a shortcut to 2k answer for 2000 and so on? I'll leave the code snippet below for understanding, and if you have any ideas it will be very helpful!

````
    const user =
      this.client.users.cache.get(args[0]) || message.mentions.users.first();

    const doc = await this.client.database.users.findOne({
      idU: message.author.id,
    });

    const money = parseInt(args[1]);

    if (!user)
      return message.quote(
        `Você deve mencionar para quem deseja enviar dinheiro.`
      )

    if (!money)
      return message.quote(
        `Você deve inserir quanto deseja enviar.`
      )

    if (user.id === message.author.id)
      return message.quote(
        `Você não pode enviar dinheiro para si mesmo.`
      )

    if (isNaN(money) || money <= 0)
      return message.quote(`Dinheiro inválido ou não reconhecido.`);

    if (money > doc.bank)
      return message.quote(
        `Você não me informou a quantidade de dinheiro ou não possui essa quantia!`
      )

    const target = await this.client.database.users.findOne({ idU: user.id });
    ```
````

Comment: Is there a reason you put this.client? Is that how you defined it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a little translator:

```js
function translateNum(str) {
var nums = str.match(/[0-9]+[kmbt]/i);
if(!nums) return parseInt(str);
var check = nums[0].toLowerCase();
var num = parseInt(check);
if(check) {
var letter = check.slice(check.length-1);
if(letter === 'k') return num*1000;
if(letter === 'm') return num*1000000;
if(letter === 'b') //... until t (trillion) if you want that
return 0; //in case an error occurs
} else {
return parseInt(str);
}
}
```

And now just run `translateNum('2k')` and it should work and return 2000 instead of 2. Any errors? Tell me!

Explanation:
str would be the number string of course, and when you put str.match(), it checks for a number, or multiple numbers followed by either k, m, b or t. Then, the rest gives out different responses depending on the letter. If there is no match with str.match(), it returns the string as a number. Also, the `i` modifier makes it case insensitive, so you can do 2K, or 2k

Comment: That error was because I added [0] to show even when the match was null (not found), now it is changed and won’t have that error

Comment: A little problem you might have would have would be if people tried something like 3.9K, this would return 9K.

Comment: Working on a way to prevent that now

Comment: it worked perfectly, thank you very much, I hope it will also serve for many who, like me, have just started!